# Get unique pairings from dictionary object in .Net

Tags: .net, linq

Suppose I have a dictionary object of String, List (of String) that looks like.

```
BU1
--All, BU
CON1
--ALL, EMP, CONF, CON1
SS1
--ALL, EMP, SS
```

How can I get an object that contains a lists of distinct matches like so...

```
ALL, ALL, ALL --> Distinct is ALL
ALL, EMP, ALL --> Distinct is ALL, EMP
ALL, EMP, EMP --> Distinct is ALL, EMP --> exists don't add
BU, ALL, ALL --> Distinct is BU, ALL
BU, EMP, ALL --> Distinct is BU, EMP, ALL
BU, EMP, EMP --> Distinct is BU, EMP
```

etc

This should be really simple and I've played with LINQ Intersect and Except and recursive functions but I haven't hit on a winning combination.

This list is just a mini example. The real list would be much bigger in both breadth and width.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Huh? How are those "lists of distinct matches"?

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one who can't figure out what his algorithm is.

Comment: it's distinct combinations of items

Comment: You keep using that word, I don't think it means what you think it means

Comment: No, I have a typo. I have other logic that strips out weighted items. I'm updating my example. It's been a long day. Sorry.

Comment: Much better! I _think_ what you're asking for is some combinatorial magic based on slicing all the values out of the dictionary. Does it have to be linq or anything that works on generic types? Maybe a cross apply and distinct would get that done, I'd have to see how that works in linq.

Comment: I'm not sold on linq. At this point whatever works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking to perform the [cartesian product](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx) of each of your lists and get the distinct tuples (each tuple containing only distinct values).

This algorithm isn't terribly efficient; it's going to generate a number of sets equal to the product of the lengths of all your lists and compare these sets to get the final distinct result.  You would need to make some minor modifications to make it case-insensitive, but you didn't say if that was required.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> Data = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
{
    {"BU1", new List<string>(){"ALL", "BU"}},
    {"CON1", new List<string>(){"ALL", "EMP", "CONF", "CON1"}},
    {"SS1", new List<string>(){"ALL", "EMP", "SS"}},
};

IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> Empty = Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Empty<string>(), 1);
Data.Aggregate(Empty, 
    (accumulator, kvp) => 
        from a in accumulator 
        from i in kvp.Value 
        select a.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(i, 1)))
    .Select(set => new HashSet<string>(set))
    .Distinct(HashSet<string>.CreateSetComparer());
```

This produces the following output sets:

```
HashSet<String> (1 item)
ALL
HashSet<String> (2 items)
ALL
EMP
HashSet<String> (2 items)
ALL
SS
HashSet<String> (3 items)
ALL
EMP
SS
HashSet<String> (2 items)
ALL
CONF
HashSet<String> (3 items)
ALL
CONF
EMP
HashSet<String> (3 items)
ALL
CONF
SS
HashSet<String> (2 items)
ALL
CON1
HashSet<String> (3 items)
ALL
CON1
EMP
HashSet<String> (3 items)
ALL
CON1
SS
HashSet<String> (2 items)
BU
ALL
HashSet<String> (3 items)
BU
ALL
EMP
HashSet<String> (3 items)
BU
ALL
SS
HashSet<String> (2 items)
BU
EMP
HashSet<String> (3 items)
BU
EMP
SS
HashSet<String> (3 items)
BU
CONF
ALL
HashSet<String> (3 items)
BU
CONF
EMP
HashSet<String> (3 items)
BU
CONF
SS
HashSet<String> (3 items)
BU
CON1
ALL
HashSet<String> (3 items)
BU
CON1
EMP
HashSet<String> (3 items)
BU
CON1
SS
```

**Update:** Here is the same algorithm in VB.NET (it looks very much the same):

```
Dim Empty As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of String)) = Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Empty(Of String)(), 1)
Data.Aggregate(Empty, _
    Function(accumulator, kvp) _
        From a in accumulator _
        From i in kvp.Value _
        Select a.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(i, 1))) _
    .Select(Function([set]) New HashSet(Of String)([set])) _
    .Distinct(HashSet(Of String).CreateSetComparer())
```

Comment: Two questions...
will this run on 3.5 or does it require 4.0?
can you convert to VB.NET? the current project is VB (I should have said that) and I don't want to have to hang a DLL off the side (but I can if I have to).

Comment: Everything used here should be supported in .NET 3.5.  I'm updating the answer to include a solution in VB.NET.